# In Solr 5.x, does zookeeper perform the tasks of load balancing and message queuing as well?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Or will I need to implement another solutions like say RabbitMQ for message queuing and some other service for load balancing along with it? Please point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up solr in CloudSolr mode. You can use the `solrj` java client implementation for load balancing the indexes and search queries to solr. [CloudSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrServer.html) is a class in the Solrj client for connecting to the Solr cloud.
It connects to Zookeeper and keeps track of the state of each node in the cluster. With this knowledge, CloudSolrServer client knows which nodes are the leaders and sends requests to leaders only to save time. Without CloudSolrServer, requests are sent in a round-robin fashion to all the Solr nodes (Leaders and Replicas). So there is S/N chance of getting the current Shard leader where N is the total number of nodes in the cloud (i.e. sum of leaders and replicas = N) and S is the number of Shard-Leaders. There are (1-S/N) chances of hitting the non-leader node which is wasteful as the non-leader node would then have to pass the request to its leader. With CloudSolrServer, requests are sent only to Shard-Leaders which performs much better.

If a node crashes, ZooKeeper notifies CloudSolrServer about the same so that CloudSolrServer removes it from the eligible solr instances' list. If a new leader is elected, then also CloudSolrServer clients are notified.

In fact, Solr actually uses the CloudSolrServer internally to communicate with other nodes in the cluster.

You don't need any type of queuing mechanism while working with Solr.

Comment: if the purpose is just to query the docs, even replicas will serve the purpose. Only new docs will be routed to the leaders